# Erro ao Passar um Objeto Para o Outro

Tags: java

Eai pessoal. Sou novo em java e esta acontecendo um erro onde eu quero passar um objeto de uma classe para outro objeto de outra classe e fica dando o seguinte erro.

**incompatible types : Paciente cannot be converted to String**. Eu sei o que significa mas não sei como arrumar o erro. A minha classe teste é a seguinte.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.Hospital;
import model.Medico;
import model.Paciente;
import model.Visitante;
import model.Doenca;


public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args){


   Paciente novoP = new Paciente("Joao da Silva", "174526", "Jardin das   flores", "1745181");
   novoP.setAlergia("Alergia a agulha");

   Visitante novoV = new Visitante("Maria do Rosario", "14751", "Jardin das Flores", "1475145");
   novoV.setEntrada("12:30");
   novoV.setSaida("2:00");

   Visitante novoV2 = new Visitante("Marta do Rosario", "14758", "Jardin das Flores", "1475125");
   novoV2.setEntrada("12:30");
   novoV2.setSaida("2:00");

   ArrayList<Visitante>visitantes = new ArrayList<>();
   visitantes.add(novoV);
   visitantes.add(novoV2);

   novoP.setVisitas(visitantes);



   Doenca novaD = new Doenca();
   novaD.setNome("Tubercolose");
   novaD.setInternado(novoP); //aqui é onde ocorre o erro, "internado" é o atributo que eu passo o objeto "novoP".



hospital(novo);
hospital(mNovo);

}    
public static void hospital(Hospital hos){
  System.out.println(hos);

}   


}
```

Classe **Paciente**

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Paciente extends Pessoa {
private String alergia;
private String idade;
private ArrayList<Visitante>visitas;

public Paciente(String nome, String cpf, String endereco, String  telefone) {
    super(nome, cpf, endereco, telefone);
}


public String getAlergia() {
    return alergia;
}

public void setAlergia(String alergia) {
    this.alergia = alergia;
}

public String getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

public void setIdade(String idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}

public ArrayList<Visitante> getVisitas() {
    return visitas;
}

public void setVisitas(ArrayList<Visitante> visitas) {
    this.visitas = visitas;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Paciente: "+super.toString()+"{" + "alergia:" + alergia + ", idade:" + idade + ", visitas:" + visitas + '}';
}







}
```

Classe **Doenca**

```
package model;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class Doenca {
 private String nome;
 private String internado;
 private String medicoNome;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getInternado() {
    return internado;
}

public void setInternado(String internado) {
    this.internado = internado;
}

public String getMedicoNome() {
    return medicoNome;
}

public void setMedicoNome(String medicoNome) {
    this.medicoNome = medicoNome;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Doenca{" + "nome:" + getNome() + ", internado:" + getInternado() + ", medicoNome:" + getMedicoNome() + '}';
}






}
```

Comment: Adiciona todas as classes envolvidas na pergunta, parece ser um erro de herança ma sem ver as classe nao tem como confirmar.

Comment: Onde dá esse erro?

Comment: Precisaria verificar como estão as outras classes, porém provavelmente o objeto Doenca está com a variável Internado como tipo String, quando ela deveria ser do tipo Paciente.

Comment: esta na classe Teste. Esta comentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está bem claro, como você mesmo constatou:

Eis o método que seta a variável `internado`:

```
public void setInternado(String internado) {...}
```

Ele recebe uma `String`. Agora, o que você está passando para esse método é um `Paciente`:

```
novaD.setInternado(novoP);
```

`novoP`, no caso, é do tipo `Paciente`, como se verifica aqui: `Paciente novoP = new Paciente(...);`

Para resolver esse erro, o melhor seria modificar sua classe `Doenca` para lidar diretamente com um objeto do tipo `Paciente`, que eu imagino que seja sua intenção (ter um paciente associado à doença), correto?

1) Em vez de `String internado`, ter um `Paciente internado`.

2) O método `setInternado()` passa a receber então um `Paciente`.

3) O método `getInternado()` passa a retornar um `Paciente`.